# Como pegar a data e hora exata após atualizar um registro?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Sempre que atualizo os dados do usuário, me retorna o horário errado, por exemplo:

Atualizei o perfil do usuário as 16:41, mas em meu banco de dados aparece assim `2019-10-15 16:10:53`

Estou usando o mysql junto com o phpmyadmin

Este é o meu array para atualizar os dados

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$data = array(
 'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d : H:m:s', time()),
);
```

Comment: Como está a data e hora do máquina em que o banco de dados se encontra?

Comment: Eu configurei o php.ini com o formato America/Sao_Paulo, mas ainda sim segue com o horário errado.

Comment: Vamos lá. O MySQL pega o horário e a timezone definida no servidor e calcula a diferença do fuso horário. Primeiro verifique se o horário definido no servidor se encontra correto.

Comment: Mas qual o horário do computador em que o MySQL está? O horário está correto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente alterar o date do update substituindo os minutos ('m') por ('i')

```
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$data = array(
 'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d : H:i:s', time()),
);
```

Manda bala e vê no que da.

Answer (score 1):

Você está inserindo o mês no lugar dos minutos. A sintaxe correta é:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())
```